# Eichler-Shimura for Shimura curves

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Hi,

What is the statement of the Eichler-Shimura relation for Shimura curves? And where
can one find a proof?

Thanks

Comment: That's the Eichler-Shimura relation for elliptic modular curves. I'm interested in the Shimura curve case.

Comment: @unknown: Oops sorry 



Comment: Take a look at Zhang's paper in

http://www.jstor.org/stable/2661372

Comment: If you choose $p$ prime to the discriminant of the quaternion algebra, I would expect it to be exactly the same as in the classical modular case.  Is this not so?

Comment: @Kevin: I guess you mean you have to stop to define the Hecke operator as a correspondence on the cusps, so we are quibbling about whether generalized enhanced elliptic curves are harder than (non-generalized) enchanced QM abelian surfaces?  Anyway, no big deal either way...

Comment: I guess it is genuinely harder over a general totally real field, because in this case there's no moduli problem and you have to resort to tricks as in Carayol's article. To the OP: the statement is in Carayol's early papers, which are specifically concerned with the arithmetic of Shimura curves and such questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general case of Shimura curves over totally real number fields, a nice exposition of the Eichler-Shimura relation is given, for example, in $\S 1.14$ of [this article](http://people.math.jussieu.fr/~nekovar/pu/euler.pdf) of J. Nekovář, where you can find pointers to the relevant literature (in particular, a standard reference is Carayol's paper mentioned therein).

Comment: Though one should point out that in fact the exposition in 1.14 of this article is faulty: the expression given is valid for the arithmetic Frobenius, but the geometric Frobenius is used. Carayol's Sur la mauvaise réduction des courbes de Shimura section 10.3 is impeccable. 

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment, Olivier! I admit that, having usually referred to Carayol's paper, I had overlooked this issue in Nekovář's article (which - with this point of caution in mind - offers a somewhat more friendly exposition of the Eichler-Shimura stuff, in my opinion). 

Comment: And now Christophe Cornut tells me that one should double check Carayol's article too: apparently, he overlooked the sign error in Deligne's Corvallis article. So maybe the best reference is Cornut Vatsal CM Points and Quaternion Algebras section 3.2.3.

Comment: Does anyone happen to know a reference that explains the implication from Carayol's to Nekovar's formulation? Even in the case of $F=\mathbb{Q}$ this would be helpful.